# Can anyone tell me why my XML writer is not writing attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I am writing a parsing tool to help me clean up a large VC++ project before I make .net bindings for it.

I am using an XML writer to read an xml file and write out each element to a new file. If an element with a certain name is found, then it executes some code and writes an output value into the elements value.

So far it is almost working, except for one thing: It is not copying the attributes. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

**Here is a sample of what it is supposed to copy/modify(Includes the attributes):**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{57900E99-A405-49F4-83B2-0254117D041B}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>libproj</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Here is the output I am getting(No Attributes):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectConfiguration>
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration>
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{57900E99-A405-49F4-83B2-0254117D041B}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>libproj</RootNamespace>
```

**Here is my code currently. I have tried every way I can come up with to write the attributes.**

```
                string baseDir = (textBox2.Text + "\\" + safeFileName);
                string vcName = Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text);
                string vcProj = Path.Combine(baseDir, vcName);

                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
                    settings.Indent = true;
                    settings.CloseOutput = false;

                    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(vcProj, settings))
                    {

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            switch (reader.NodeType)
                            {
                                case XmlNodeType.Element:

                                   if (reader.Name == "ClInclude")
                                    {
                                        string include = reader.GetAttribute("Include"); 
                                        string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox1.Text);
                                        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirPath);
                                        string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(include);
                                        //string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);

                                        copyFile(fullPath, 3);
                                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
                                        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                                        writer.WriteAttributeString("Include", "include/" + filename);
                                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                                    }
                                    else if (reader.Name == "ClCompile" && reader.HasAttributes)
                                    {
                                        string include = reader.GetAttribute("Include"); 
                                        string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox1.Text);
                                        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirPath);
                                        string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(include);

                                        copyFile(fullPath, 2);
                                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
                                        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                                        writer.WriteAttributeString("Include", "src/" + filename);
                                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                                    } 
                                   else
                                    {
                                        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                                    }

                                    break;

                                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                                    writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                                    break;
                                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                                    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                                    break;
                                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                                    writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                                    break;
                                case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                                    writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                                    break;
                                case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                                    writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Value);
                                    break;
                               case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                                    writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                                    break;

                                }
                        }

                    }

                }
```

Comment: I'm almost sure your problem is your ignorance of the XML namespaces and\or "ConformanceLevel.Fragment"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I added ConformanceLevel.Fragment after I received an error stating that I needed to add it due to invalid XML. I had actually removed it while trying different options, although when creating a reproduction I accidently added it again. It makes no difference as far as the output whether it is added or not. Although please explain why my ignorance in that matter is the problem?

Comment: @Soonts You were essentially right. My issue was with my ignorance of the XML namespaces, and lack thereof. I also changed my conformance level to Auto. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up looking a bit ore into namespaces after Soonts comment, and realized why one of my attempts was not working. I had to specify the namespace beforehand, instead of allowing the writer to copy it into the reader XML file. Here is how I solved my issue:

```
                        string baseDir = (textBox2.Text + "\\" + safeFileName);
                        string vcName = Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text);
                        string vcProj = Path.Combine(baseDir, vcName);

                        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(textBox1.Text))
                        {
                            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                            //settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
                            settings.Indent = true;
                            settings.CloseOutput = false;
                            string nameSpace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
                            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(vcProj, settings))
                            {

                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                                    {
                                        case XmlNodeType.Element:

                                           if (reader.Name == "ClInclude")
                                            {
                                                string include = reader.GetAttribute("Include"); 
                                                string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox1.Text);
                                                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirPath);
                                                string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(include);
                                                //string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
                                                //MessageBox.Show("Path: " + dirPath + Environment.NewLine + "Filename: " + filename);
                                                copyFile(fullPath, 3);
                                                string filename = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
                                                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name, nameSpace);
                                                writer.WriteAttributeString("Include", "include/" + filename);
                                                writer.WriteEndElement();

                                            }
                                            else if (reader.Name == "ClCompile" && reader.HasAttributes)
                                            {
                                                string include = reader.GetAttribute("Include"); 
                                                string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox1.Text);
                                                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirPath);
                                                string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(include);
                                                //string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
                                                //MessageBox.Show("Path: " + dirPath + Environment.NewLine + "Filename: " + filename);
                                                copyFile(fullPath, 2);
                                                string filename = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
                                                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name, nameSpace);
                                                writer.WriteAttributeString("Include", "src/" + filename);
                                                writer.WriteEndElement();

                                            } 
                                           else
                                            {
                                                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name, nameSpace);
                                                writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                                            }

                                            break;

                                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                                            writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                                            break;
                                        case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                                        case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                                            writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                                            break;
                                        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                                            writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                                            break;
                                        case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                                            writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                                            break;
                                        case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                                            writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Value);
                                            break;
                                       case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                                            writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                                            break;

                                        }
                                }

                            }

                        }
```